# Switching Oracle schemas by using different users in the connection string

Tags: oracle

I usually work with MSSQL but have an Oracle project on my hand that needs solving. Parts of the environment I am working with are not completely in my control so I have not free reign.

Problem: There is one Oracle server, containing two schemas. Let's call them:

1. Schema_Live
2. Schema_Test

Both schemas are identical, with the obvious difference that one is for testing and the other for the real application.

Now I was given an already existing web service that generates reports on this database. All is working fine so far, but the existing user we are working with, let's call him "oldUser", has to be given the schema names if he should work. So for example the query:

```
SELECT foo FROM Schema_Live.exampleTable WHERE id = 1
```

[executed]--> foo = 'live'
or

```
SELECT foo FROM Schema_Test.exampleTable WHERE id = 1
```

[executed]--> foo = 'test'

works, but we don't want to change our queries all the time before deploying, so as a already existing workaround the schema will be switched automatically by code, before the query is executed:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = Schema_Test
```

[executed]

```
SELECT foo FROM exampleTable WHERE id = 1
```

[executed]--> foo = 'test'

If that is not done, we will get the error "Table or view does not exist":

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: "ORA-00942: Tabelle oder View nicht vorhanden"

SELECT foo FROM exampleTable WHERE id = 1
```

[executed]--> ORA-00942

There are also existing reports that are using their own connections to get their data, which is the main problem, because in these queries we have to include the schema names due to no chance of executing "ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA" before. Deploying these includes find/replace the schema names, which is as faulty as it sounds.

My solution: As far as I understood the Oracle philosophy (and please correct me if I am wrong), I can not simply change the database name (= schema name) in the connection string, like I would do in MSSQL. There are no "database" properties in the Oracle connection string, because Oracle users are already hardwired to their schema.

So, to solve that, I want to create to different users:

- User_Live -> hardwired to "Schema_Live"
- User_Test -> hardwired to "Schema_Test"

and implement two different connection strings that are given to the reports and queries I'll execute. If I do that, the query

```
SELECT foo FROM exampleTable WHERE id = 1
```

will give me
foo = 'test' for User_Test 
and
foo = 'live' for User_Live

Question 1: Is that concept sound or is there a mistake in it?

Question 2: My problem is now that I was given two users but the query

```
SELECT foo FROM exampleTable WHERE id = 1
```

gives me ORA-00942 for both users. I think the admin created them wrong, but I'm lacking all the know-how to check and tell him what he did wrong.

P.S.:

Using one of the new users and execute the query works:

```
SELECT foo FROM Schema_Test.exampleTable WHERE id = 1
```

[executed]--> foo = 'test'

Soo I am guessing atm that there is only a DefaultTablespace problem and not a problem with access rights

Comment: You may consider to create a **database** for testing, not just a user. Then you can run the same code on either DB's. Another note: Unlike SQL Server in Oracle a "Schema" is basically the same as a "User". Well, of course it is not the same, however it is not possible to unlink them.

Comment: Hi thx so far, one question: I don't want to "unlink" something, I want to connect with connectionstring A to talk to Schema A and connectionsstring B to talk to Schema B. So: No "unlinking" of something :)

Comment: Better skip my note, you already noticed that *Oracle users are already hardwired to their schema* - that's what I mean.

Comment: Not really my area, but you might have a look at [proxy authentication (`connect through`)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/proxya.htm) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

"ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = Schema_Test"

will persist the duration of a session.  So (on the assumption you are not using connection pooling), you can issue this once as part of a logon trigger, and then you should be good for the duration of the session.

```
SQL>
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.

SQL> create user demo identified by demo;

User created.

SQL> grant connect to demo;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant select on scott.emp to demo;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn demo/demo
Connected.

SQL> select count(*) from scott.emp;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

1 row selected.

SQL> select count(*) from emp;
select count(*) from emp
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL>
SQL>
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.

SQL> create or replace
  2  trigger demo_login
  3  after logon on demo.schema
  4  begin
  5   execute immediate 'alter session set current_schema = scott';
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
SQL> conn demo/demo
Connected.

SQL> select count(*) from scott.emp;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

1 row selected.

SQL> select count(*) from emp;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

1 row selected.

SQL>
```

or example using proxies

```
SQL> create user demo identified by demo;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to demo;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> alter user scott grant connect through demo;

User altered.

SQL> conn demo[scott]/demo
Connected.

SQL> select user from dual;

USER
--------------------------------------------------------------------
SCOTT

1 row selected.

SQL> select count(*) from emp;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

1 row selected.
```

Comment: Hey, thx for the input. Part of the problem is that the database is managed by another product and we are providing "additional" services unconnected to the main product. But I'll check with the admins how much access we have. Also we use pooling and also the reports use their own connections, so we need another solution then just alter the session once :)

Comment: Yeah, once you get into connection pooling territory, things get more complicated because "clients" need to explicitly set/reset their session settings each time they get a connection from the pool.  And if you don't have control over that, then you're out of luck on the "alter session" front.

I've done an addenda on my answer showing the proxy user route